# Javascript overriding CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a simple site in Laravel 5.7. It has a jquery based slider, displaying pictures. I would like to display pictures in the slides background, based on model data passed from controler.

```
@foreach($slider_projects as $slider_project)
<div class="slide slide-{{$slider_index}}">
    <div class="slide__bg" style="background-image:url({{asset($slider_project->image)}})"></div>
    <div class="slide__content">
    </div>
</div>
{{$slider_index++}}
@endforeach
```

But my problem is, that the *style* attribute of my div is being overriden by js code responsible for displaying the slider properly:

```
$slideBGs = $(".slide__bg"),
$slideBGs.css("transform", "translate3d("+ curSlide*50 +"%,0,0)");
```

*background-image* property is not appearing anymore in *style__bg* divs.

What would be the best approach to render the slider content (background images) dynamically, without disturbing its behaviour (js part)?

Comment: Is your `background-image` setting being removed after the slider code has run? - the code you have posted shouldn't by itself by responsible for removing the `background-image` property...

Comment: Yes, when posted above js code is commented, the *background-image* property appears properly

Comment: So why not just comment it? Because it is in the plugin's .js file?

Comment: Because it would disturb slider's desired behaviour.